# How to browse the .csv file to perform an operation on it using python?

Tags: python

I have a .csv file (raw report) and I have written a python script to perform some operations on it.

The script is working fine and I am executing this script using terminal.

My requirement is: I have mentioned the raw .csv file name in the script to open and perform few operations on it, so can I browse the file, instead of writing the file name in script (because sometimes the file name changes which I want to automate).

"File name is changing randomly" I don't want to edit my script daily.

Comment: `import sys` and `file_path = sys.argv[-1]`. Then you can do `python myScript.py randomfilename.csv` on the commandline

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have control over the filename, you can fetch the csv file dynamically assuming it will be the only file in directory

```
from os import listdir
csv_file = [file for file in listdir(path_to_csv_file_dir) if file.endswith('.csv')]
print(csv_file[0])
```

Comment: I did not understand it. Could you please elaborate more? Above syntax throwing an error as invalid syntax.

Comment: can you paste the syntax error? it works on my system and gives the list of all csv files in a given directory

Comment: Should I write the above import statement on top of the script ?can you share the screen shot of your script ?

Comment: Yes you can try that. "path_to_csv_file_dir" will be the folder directory in which your csv file resides and "csv_file[0]" will be your file name. if you can paste your code here, it will be easy for the community to help you where it needs to be modified

Comment: Getting error like:Traceback (most recent call ): File "browse file.py" line 3 in <module> csv_file = [file for file in listdir(patch_to_csv_file_dir) if.endwith('.csv')] NameError: name 'patch_to_csv_file_dir' is not defined

Comment: from os import listdir csv_file = [file for file in listdir(path_to_csv_file_dir) if file.endswith('.csv')] print(csv_file[0]) I just written this code so should I initialise valuable to store the .csv file?

Comment: You are getting error because path_to_csv_file_dir is not defined. It should be the directory path where you have your cvs file, like 'C:\folder'.

Comment: Ok,should I create directory in my system as patch_to_csv_file_dir ?

Comment: Yeah. You can use the syntax     path_to_csv_file_dir = 'C:\folder'

Comment: Ohh ok, I have to initialise the variable called path_to_csv_file_dir = 'Here I should mention the csv file path' right ?

Comment: No. You need to mention the folder where the cvs file is located

Comment: Script:
import sys
from os import listdir
csv_file = [file for file in listdir(patch_to_csv_file_dir)
 if file.endwith('.csv')]
print (csv_file[0])
patch_to_csv_file_dir='/home/mahaknur/Desktop/patch_to_csv_file_dir'



Error while running:
[mahaknur@oc0463620485 patch_to_csv_file_dir]$ python2 browse\ file.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "browse file.py", line 3, in <module>
    csv_file = [file for file in listdir(patch_to_csv_file_dir) if file.endwith('.csv')]
NameError: name 'patch_to_csv_file_dir' is not defined
[mahaknur@oc0463620485 patch_to_csv_file_dir]$

Comment: Now how can I use this .csv file dynamically in my program?